# Two sequential heredocs in PHP?

Tags: php, heredoc

What's wrong with the following code:

```
static function queryVariables($variable_name)
    {

        $query = <<<SQL
SELECT * 
  FROM variables v 
    WHERE v.nam = '$variable_name'
SQL;    

    $ans = self::$conn->select($query);


      $query = <<<SQL
SELECT v.id, v.nam variable_nam, v.descr variable_descr, us.id subset_id, us.unit_id, us.ord, us.nam subset_nam, us.color, us.min_value, us.max_value 
  FROM variables v 
    LEFT JOIN unit_subsets us ON v.unit_id = us.unit_id
    WHERE v.nam = '$variable_name'
SQL;

        $ans = self::$conn->select($query);

        return $ans;
    }
```

I know it is logically incorrect, because overwrites `$query` variable. But the question is: why it doesn't understand there are two heredocs here? It treats entire block as one heredoc and throws

```
Undefined variable: ans
```

exception because it tries to embed `$ans` into heredoc.

How to fix?

Comment: Putting two heredocs one after the other like this works fine for me in a test file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see spaces after `SQL;` closing identifier. You can't have them. Semicolon must be the last character before newline.

```
SQL;    
    ^^^^^^^
```

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

The first appearance of `SQL;` in the posted code is followed, on the same line, by a bunch of white spaces. Remove them and it will work as you intended.